# Leetcode Q3 - Why return and instead of (ans+1)?

Tags: java

Leetcode link:
https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/

The following is my code using set:

```
class Solution {
    public int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
        char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
        int n = s.length();
        int left = 0, right = 0, ans = 0;
        Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>(); 
        if (s == null || s.length() == 0) return ans;
        
        while (left < n && right < n) {
            if (!set.contains(arr[right])) set.add(arr[right++]);
            else {
                while (set.contains(arr[right])) {
                    set.remove(arr[left++]);
                }
            }
            ans = Math.max(ans, right - left);
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

My understanding, for example, `[a,b,c,a]`, when `right = 3`, `left = 0`, then set *remove 'a'* (whose index is 0), `left++`, so, `left = 1`, then, it should return (3-1)+1.

Comment: It will actually go to left=1, right=4 in the next iteration, which produces right-left==3 (again, the first one was abc). And only after that it will fall out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why `ans` recalculation should even be the last line of that outer `while` loop, which is executed regardless of `set.contains` check.

See, the only way for substring to expand is in `if` branch:

```
if (!set.contains(arr[right])) set.add(arr[right++])
```

... which basically means "ok, so we can extend the current substring one more time, no repeats yet".

While `right - left` expression seems to be missing the true length of that substring by one (if right and left = 0, substring's length is 1 actually), that's compensated by that increment (`right++`) in the previous line.

So the expression actually should be read as "this loop's initial right - this loop's initial left + 1"), and in your example the maximum is reached on 'c' check, not on 'a' check.

Now, for 'else' branch the non-repeating substring never gets extended: all the code does is contracting it (from its left side) by increasing the value of `left` (at least by one: if we got there, `left++` is executed at least once).

But if `right` is not increased, and `left` can only go up, `right - left` value by definition can only go down, right? That makes `Math.max` destined to fail if it's executed right after `else` branch code.

Answer (score 0):

Iterations for [a,b,c,a]

1. Set {a}, l=0, r=1 , max = 1
2. Set {a, b}, l=0, r=2 , max = 2
3. Set {a,b,c}, l=0, r=3, max =3
4. Set {b,c}, l=1, r=3, max= 3
5. Set {b,c,a}, l=1, r=4, max=3

This should help getting a gist on how this algorithm is working.